# ¿Varios datos para un dato especifico en SQL? ¿Array?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, tablas

¡Buenos días!, me dejaron una tarea en la universidad, y pensé... ¡ah esta sencilla!, ya que pues manejo bien las sentencias básicas que necesito de crear, alterar, eliminar, actualizar y demás, también pues se acerca de los datos básicos que maneja mysql, sin embargo no nos enseñaron en ninguna parte como podrían manejarse arrays dentro de SQL (O por lo menos eso pensé en usar cuando vi lo que realmente necesitaba).

Para primero contextualizar sobre que trata mi tarea o actividad, este es el enunciado:

**Tomando como base una empresa del mundo real y un proceso particular identifique las entidades de las que desea almacenar datos.**

Por ejemplo: para una empresa comercializadora es necesario la información de:

- Clientes: Cliente de la comercializadora.
- Referencias comerciales de clientes: Información de referencias comerciales del cliente.
- Productos: Productos en venta de la comercializadora.
- Empleados: Empleados de la comercializadora.
- Facturas: Relación del consecutivo de facturas.
- Ventas por factura y producto: Discriminación de cada ítem de la factura, cada ítem se asocia a cada producto vendido en la factura.
- Lista de precios: Lista de precios de los productos de la comercializadora.

Yo escogí un almacén llamado olímpico, este vende equipamiento deportivo (Creo que se puede), ya que a fin de cuentas un almacen puede considerarse como una pequeña empresa.

Para la arquitectura de **UNA** de las tablas de la base de datos de esta compañía, identifique los siguientes datos:

```
nombre_tabla: factura_compra
campos:

N#compra: bigInt PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT
nombre_cliente: varchar(35) NOT NULL
nombre_articulo: varchar(30) UNIQUE
precio_articulo: bigInt NOT NULL
cantidad_articulo: int
total_compra: bigInt
```

El caso es que... ¿Y si son varios artículos los que compro el cliente?, ¿como se haría para que pudiese añadir varios artículos a la factura de compra del cliente y la cantidad de cada uno de ellos?, no se... estoy un poco confundido... ¿o estoy errado y es otra cosa la que debo hacer para resolver lo de la factura?.

**NOTA:** los datos de arriba son solo un esquema, es decir, se que así no es como se añade esos datos a una tabla, se como agregar estos datos, pero no se lo del array o con que estructura o como debería hacerse y de que manera para poder hacer lo que esta en el párrafo anterior...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para esto, no debes utilizar un array, debes separar los datos, que es parte de normalizar una base de datos.

Respecto a tu pregunta, existen varias formas para hacerlo, una de ellas es la siguiente:

Si el almacén realiza una venta, esta tiene asociada productos (1 a N). a su vez, la venta es para un cliente.

por ende una venta incluye productos y, a su vez, tiene asociada un cliente.

Una de las soluciones podría ser así(si la base de datos es relacional):

tabla clientes:

id_cliente (entero)

nombre_cliente (string)

tabla ventas:

id_venta (entero)

fecha_venta (datetime)

id_cliente_fk (entero, id del cliente asociada a la venta)

tabla productos:

id_producto (entero)

nombre_producto (string)

precio_producto (entero)

tabla ventas_productos (tabla intermedia entre ventas y productos, nos ayuda asociar una venta a uno o muchos productos).

id_venta (entero, id de la tabla venta)
id_producto (entero, id de un producto)

Entonces:

si compras 10 productos serán insertados con el id de la venta en la tabla ventas_productos, con eso ya puedes asociar la venta a un cliente y saber que productos tiene esa venta.

ejemplo:

la venta con id = 1 corresponde a una compra  de dos productos con id=2, un producto id=3 y un producto id=5

tabla ventas_productos

id_venta - id_producto

1        - 2

1        - 2

1        - 3

1        - 5

así puedes asociar uno o mas productos a una venta.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!, me basare en tu respuesta para crear las tablas.